# External Css file not linked to HTML page - refresh not working (See edit for solution)

Tags: html, css

I coded a simple web page with a nav bar but the relative external css file is not loaded, even after refreshing the page once opened and even when I paste the full path. (Edit: added css code; Edit2: the css code works if embedded in the index file, I also overcame the Error shown in comments. Still nothing. OK, final edit... I just saved the same css file again substituting the existing one and it worked. If you have the same problem check if you can open the css in the browser from the source code. If not you have a problem with the file. Just try saving it again as a css file in the same css folder.)

Here's the code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css"/>
      </head>
      <body>
```

So my question is, what should I do now to make the web page load the css style sheet properly?

```
.nav{
height: 50px;
background:blue;
}
.nav div{
display: inline-block;
position:absolute;
left:0;
padding:15px;
font-size:20px;
color:white;
}
.nav ul{
position:absolute;
right:5px;
}
.nav ul li{
display:inline-block;
}
.nav ul li a{
color:white;
padding:5px;
}
```

Comment: Did you check the browser console for errors? Does the CSS file have the proper permissions?

Comment: @j08691 I checked the console for errors and I get this: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND". Now, I've got the same folder for every file...the index...the css and so on. It's all in one folder in the user folder. What am I missing here?

Comment: If the files are in the same folder all you need it `href="style.css"` or `href="/style.css"`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about your css file address?
I suggest you to move your css file in the root of your project and change your address like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
```

If it will be work then you should resolve your css address and move your file.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to press CTRL + F5 to clear your browser cache, or failing that add a meaningless parameter to the css link to force the browser to take the latest file instead of a cached version eg add ?version=1.1

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css?version=1.1"/>
```

Comment: Tried both methods, nothing happened. Should I do something at another level maybe?

Comment: What is the directory structure of the project ?

Comment: I have a folder containing the file index.html and three sub-folders: javascript, css and images. (It's all in my user folder for simplicity)

Comment: Does it work when you move the file to the root with the index.html and adjust the lint to href="style.css" ?      You can also try keeping your existing structure , but change the link to href="css/style.css"

Comment: I'm sorry, can you please explain what moving the file to the root is? Same level in a folder? Or inside the html file? 

I've already tried moving the vss file at the same folder level of the index.html file and nothing happened.

Edit: Tried also using the css/style.css reference but again, nothing changed.

Comment: The root is the base directory of the project, and is likely the same folder you have the index.html file. Eg  Your folder is called  "MyWebProject" and inside this is the index.html, along with the folders for JS , CSS etc

Comment: Also, when using url , when not working on a server try avoiding using absolute paths i.e urls that start with "/" as this makes it relative to the root of the website, and if youre using your local machine the root of the website will be the C drive.